# open and pass text to program in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new to Batch files. I Need to start a .exe from my Batch file. 
This starts a prompt where I need to Input a word and press enter. How can this be done?

This is what i currently have:

```
@echo off
title run_thermo
start prgrm_x64.exe
pause
```

I already tried

```
start prgrm_x64.exe > inputtext  
start prgrm_x64.exe < inputtext  
start prgrm_x64.exe | inputtext
```

-->work on 64bit win10pro
thanks for any help

Comment: What's the use of this? Can't you just double-click on the program, the program asks for the input, you give it, and off you go? Why do you want to pass via a batchfile if your program is interactive?

Comment: It is simply more time efficient... if I Need to do a Parameter study and want to start multiple instances of the program with different Inputs.

Comment: The `start` command opens the application in a new window. Is that what you want or do you want to start it in the existing window?

Comment: `echo inputtext|prgrm_x64.exe`. Whether it works depends, how the exe is programmed.

Comment: echo inputtext|prgrm_x64.exe  worked!! thx

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to use the '<' operator to pass input into the 'standard input' of the program. Normally, 'standard input' is connected to the console (aka keyboard) so you have to type some input, but on the command line you can use '<' to specify a file (or any other data stream) as the standard input for the program you're starting.

Whether this works for the specific program you're working with is another question, but it's the first thing to try.

See also https://superuser.com/questions/752648/how-can-i-feed-a-file-into-a-program-that-reads-stdin-on-windows-command-line

Comment: thanks, I tried: "start prgrm_x64.exe < Input" and also ">" and "/" doesen't work

Comment: I see you have a solution now, but to explain further - 'start prgrm_x64.exe < input' didn't work because in that case, the program you're running is 'start', and the content of 'input' is being passed to the standard input of 'start', which likely just ignores it. That's because 'start' is a separate program that takes the name of your program as a parameter and then launches it. Just doing 'prgrm_x64 < input' would work and is functionally equivalent to 'echo input | prgrm_x64'.

Comment: @Chris: not quite: `echo input|program` gives the string `input` to the program. `program < input` would try to give the content of a file named `input` to the program.